# A Geometry Question，maybe have something to do with specular reflection

Tags: geometry

Let us assume that a billiard ball which strikes a flat wall will bounce off in such a way that the two lines of the path followed by the ball (before and after the collision) make equal angles with the wall. Consider $n$ lines $D_1,D_2,...,D_n$ in the plane, and points $A,B$ on the same side of all of these lines. In what direction should a billiard ball be shot from $A$ in order that it arrive at $B$ after having bounced off each of the given lines successively? Show that the path followed by the ball in this case is the shortest broken line going from $A$ to $B$ and having successive vertices on the given lines.

*Special Case.* The given lines are the four sides of rectangle, taken in their natural order; the point $B$ coincides with $A$ and is inside the  rectangle. Show that, in this case, the path travelled by the ball is equal to the sum of the diagonals of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Reflect point $B$ across line $D_n$, then $D_{n-1}$...